# Collectors.groupingBy functionality and summing a field

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Point::getCount)));
```

I have a list of `Point` objects that I want to group by a certain key (the `name` field) and sum by the `count` field of that class. The code above does the job but returns a map of `Point` objects. However, I want a list of `Point` objects returned - **not a map**.

What is the cleanest way to do this with java 8 streams?

Example:

```
input = [pt("jack", 1), pt("jack", 1), pt("jack", 1)]

result = [pt("jack", 3)]
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, java streams wise I think you could stream the `Entry`s from the Map and map them to a list. Seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you were close.   You can take the `key (name)` and `value (point sum)` and repackage it into a new `Point` object and return as a list.  Note that by re-assiging to `list`, you destroy the original one which will of course be garbage collected.  This approach does not require a modification of your current class.

```
list = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getName,
                        Collectors.summingInt(Point::getCount)))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new Point(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I like this approach. Very clean. It doesn't mutate existing objects but creates new ones with the Map function below. It is definitely something I will remember for the future to stream the map. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Collectors.toMap()` with a merge function as parameter.

If you add a function to sum `count` fields:

```
public class Point {
    //... 
    public static Point sum(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return new Point(p1.getName(), p1.getCount()+p2.getCount());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in `toMap()`:

```
List<Point> list = Collections.nCopies(10, new Point("jack", 1));

Collection<Point> output = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Point::getName, Function.identity(), Point::sum)) // results as Map<String, Point> {"jack", Point("jack",10)}
        .values(); // to get the Point instances

System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
[Point [name=jack, count=10]]
```

Comment: This is what I  was trying to do but I could not find the syntax to make it work. Thanks my friend

Comment: Modifying incoming `Point` instances is a bad idea. Try with input `List<Point> list = Collections.nCopies(10, new Point("jack", 1));`

Comment: @Holger I couldn't figure it out. As if there is only one `Point` reference, it gives wrong result. Should I modify the `sum()` or do it in a different way... Can you explain this a little bit please?

Comment: The `sum()` function should create a new `Point` instance instead of modifying incoming arguments. That would also be important when using parallel streams. If the amount of newly created objects ever becomes a concern, a `collect` based approach should be used.

Answer (score 2):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Pointers {
    private String  name;
    private int  count;

    public Pointers(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void incrementCount(int amount) {
        count += amount;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equal = false;
        if (obj instanceof Pointers) {
            Pointers other = (Pointers) obj;
            equal = name.equals(other.getName());
        }
        return equal;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return name + count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pointers> list = List.of(new Pointers("Jack", 1),
                                      new Pointers("Jack", 1),
                                      new Pointers("Jack", 1));
        Supplier<List<Pointers>> supplier = () -> new ArrayList<Pointers>();
        BiConsumer<List<Pointers>, Pointers> accumulator = (l, p) -> {
            if (l.contains(p)) {
                Pointers elem = l.get(l.indexOf(p));
                elem.incrementCount(p.getCount());
            }
            else {
                l.add(p);
            }
        };
        BiConsumer<List<Pointers>, List<Pointers>> combiner = (l1, l2) -> {
            
        };
        List<Pointers> lst = list.stream()
                                 .collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);
        System.out.println(lst);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post / answer but @Hulya's answer was more in line with what I was looking to do.